# Is this case a failure of Stokes' theorem?

Tags: electromagnetism, differential-geometry, singularities, magnetic-monopoles, dirac-string

In the presence of a hypothetical magnetic point charge at the origin of coordinates, it turns out that an irremovable physical singularity of the vector potential ${\bf A}({\bf r})$ exists for any choice of ${\bf A}({\bf r})$, extending from the origin to infinity in a radially outward direction. This is called the Dirac string. Let us consider a particular choice of ${\bf A}({\bf r})$ such that the Dirac string lies along the positive $z$ axis. This choice is
$${\bf A}({\bf r}) = \frac{g}{r(r-z)}(y\hat{{ x}}-x\hat{{y}}),\nonumber\\
~~~~= -\frac{g(1+\cos\theta)}{r\sin\theta}\hat{{\phi}}.
$$ There is a genuine singularity at $\theta=0$ i.e. on the entirety of positive $z$-axis!

Now consider the following steps. First, consider a punctured sphere with its center at the origin and the punctured disc pierced by the positive $z$ axis such that the Dirac string passes through the disc. Next, consider a closed loop $C$ and along the circumference of the disc enclosing the Dirac string.

Is Stokes' theorem valid here? I recall from memory that Stokes' theorem is valid if *both* the surface and the loop enclosing surface are in a region where the vector field is free from singularities. In this particular situation, the loop $C$, as well as the curved surface of the sphere enclosed by the loop, lie in a singularity-free region of ${\bf A}({\bf r})$. However, if we consider the circular puncture enclosed by the loop, this disc not free from the singularity. Because it is pierced by the positive $z$-axis.

Comment: 1. Why do you doubt the applicability of Stokes' theorem in this case? Your question is written as if you have good reason to believe it fails, but you never tell us what that reason is. You even give the correct prerequisite for applying it - the lack of singularities on the surface involved. 2. The integrals along your $C_1$ and $C_2$ are always unequal (unless they vanish) - the different orientation means that $\int_{C_1} = -\int_{C_2}$.

Comment: 1. But the vector field is singular on the disc. That is yet another surface enclosed by the loop. This makes me worry whether Stokes' theorem is valid here. 2. This question is predicated on the assumption that Stokes' theorem fails here. What I really wanted to ask is that if Stokes' theorem ever fails due a singularity of the vector field, how it fails. @ACuriousMind

Comment: I still don't understand what you're asking for. You say *"I recall from memory that Stokes' theorem is valid if both the surface and the loop enclosing surface are in a region where the vector field is free from singularities."* This is correct - if there's a singularity in the surface involved, you can't apply the theorem. What exactly is your question about that? What does the difference between the two integrals due to the different orientation of $C_1$ and $C_2$ have to do with Stokes' theorem at all?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. There are two surfaces. Right? What if I consider the surface pierced by $z$ axis? On that surface, the vector field is singular. I have removed the ambiguous part from the question.

Comment: @ACuriousMind is correct. Stokes theorem is doing precisely what it's suppose to, the standard vector calculus statements are just only valid for trivial homology, which is not the case here. Furthermore, I'm unclear on why you're asking about "consequences [for] physics." You are describing precisely the construction of the Dirac monopole. You seem to be aware of this as you refer to the Dirac string...

Comment: @RichardMyers Ya, I am aware of Dirac monopoles. But deriving Dirac's quantization condition requires using two different choices of ${\bf A}$ in two different regions. Well, I believe I had two different questions in mind and somehow I mixed them up. I'll try to post a separate question. Here, I just want to know if Stokes' theorem fails or not. The reason I am not sanguine is that one of the surfaces is not singularity-free.

Comment: I suggest seeing the first chapter of David Tong's [gauge theory](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/gaugetheory.html) book. It covers both questions you seem to have. In brief I will point out that we are *forced* to have two different $A$'s specifically so the field has no singularities present in it.

Answer (score 6):

In this kind of cohomology-related things, physicists tend to say that “Stokes theorem always holds,” while allowing the possibility of delta-function sources.
On the other hand, mathematicians normally exclude the delta-like sources from the domain of their spaces and say that “you cannot apply Stokes theorem when the ‘inner region’ (the inverse-boundary operation) of the submanifold of integration is not well-defined.“

Take a current $I$ flowing through an infinite line, for example.
The magnetic field is $(\mu_0 I/2\pi) (1/s)\hat{\phi}$.
Physicists say that Stokes’ theorem $\mu_0\int_\mathcal{S} \vec{J}\cdot d^2\vec{a} = \oint_{\partial\mathcal{S}} \vec{B}\cdot d\vec{l}$ holds perfectly well, as the current density is given by $\vec{J}(x,y,z) = I\delta(x)\delta(y) \hat{z}$.
But, mathematicians say that “you cannot call a loop enclosing the current line ‘$\partial\mathcal{S}$’!”
It is because, the surface $\mathcal{S}$ filling the loop “$\partial\mathcal{S}$” passes through the line, where the magnetic field diverges.
In mathematician’s standards, the “space” is not $\mathbb{R}^3$ but $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{x=0,y=0\}$, the current line being removed.
Then it has a nontrivial topology and a nontrivial cohomology class…
If we imagine $\mathcal{S}$ as a soap membrane, then it will “burst” when it touches the “spiky” delta-like $\nabla\times\vec{B}$, screaming like “ouch”!!

Your original question about magnetic monopole can be also understood in this way.
For physicists, applying the Stokes theorem is never a problem at all because they will always push their “black magic with delta distributions” to the end.
For instance see Nakahara’s “Geometry, Topology, and Physics” for the current density of the Dirac string: an infinitesimally thin half-infinite solenoid.
It is expressed in terms of Dirac delta and Heaviside step function.
On the other hand, mathematicians will say that the “space” is not the entire Euclidean space but $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\}$ so that you cannot call the Gauss surface enclosing the magnetic monopole “$\partial\mathcal{V}$” because there is no such thing as “$\mathcal{V}$” that can “survive” after passing through the spiky singularity at the origin.
They just exclude the origin from the domain of the magnetic field, because it blows up there.
(Note that physicists *include* the origin as the domain of the magnetic field and even write down equations like $\nabla\cdot\vec{B}=g\delta(x)\delta(y)\delta(z)$.)
Then they will work in the manner precisely you have described in your question: introducing Dirac string, coordinate patches, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The Stokes' theorem
$$
  \oint_{C(S)} \vec{A}(\vec{r}) \cdot d\vec{\ell} = \int\int_S \vec\nabla\times\vec{A}\cdot d\vec{S}.
$$

Therefore, any closed contour integral vanishes only when $\vec\nabla\times\vec{A} = 0$ (which then implys that the integral between two points will not depend on the path of integral).

In your case, the $\vec\nabla\times\vec{A}$ is:

$$
\vec\nabla\times\vec{A} = \frac{1}{r^2\sin\theta}
\left\vert
\begin{matrix}
\hat{r} & r\hat{\theta} & r\sin\theta\hat{\phi}\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial r} &\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} &\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} \\
0 & 0& r\sin\theta \frac{g(1+\cos\theta)}{r\sin\theta}
\end{matrix}
\right\vert
= \frac{1}{r^2\sin\theta} \hat{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} g(1+\cos\theta)
= -\hat{r}\frac{g}{r^2}
$$

The $\vec\nabla\times\vec{A} \ne 0$, therefore the integral between two points will be depended on path of integral.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have to be worried about the non-analyticity of the gauge potential on the Dirac string, when deducing Dirac's quantization:

With your choice of potential ${\bf{A}} = -g\frac{(1+\cos\theta)}{r\sin\theta}\,\hat{\phi} = -\frac{g}{r}\cot\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$, there is a singular line (Dirac string) on the positive $z$ axis as you correctly mentioned. In order to get to Dirac's quantization result, consider a pinched sphere S containing the pole (very similar to yours), and has a tiny hole around $\theta = 0$ somewhere on the $z$ axis, from within which the Dirac string goes through. You can, without any issues, use the Stokes' theorem for this surface S having the tiny circular hole C as its boundary. (Yes you are right that you cannot use Stoke's theorem if instead we were trying to work with the tiny cap surface on the upper hemisphere of S, which we have discarded).

Consider a charged particle (electric charge e) and let us move it around this ever so tiny loop C. The total phase accumulated in its wave function would be equal to $e\oint_c \mathrm{d}{\bf{l}}\cdot{\bf{A}} = \int\mathrm{d}{\bf{S}}\cdot{\bf{B}} = 4\pi e g$. The first equality comes about on account of using Stoke's theorem, which as we said above holds just fine for our surface. (To convince yourself you can explicitly calculate the line integral for your choice of potential and see it is the same as the radius of C becomes ever so tiny.) Now this phase accumulated cannot be anything but some integer multiple of one full rotation, $2\pi n$, since the wave function has to be well behaved (continuous). This gives $2eg = n$.

We can repeat this exercise for any other choice of $\bf{A}$ for which the Dirac string was lying somewhere else. For instance you can perform a $\textit{large}$ gauge transformation on your original $\bf{A}$: $\bf{A} \rightarrow \bf{A} + \nabla\alpha$ with $\alpha = g\phi$, to now get ${\bf{A}} = -g\cot(\theta)\hat{\phi}$. This time you have two Dirac strings! One on the positive $z$ axis and another on the negative $z$ axis. We can play the same game as above, this time having two punctures on both the northern and southern hemisphere. We will get the same quantization condition.